# How to make the camera track from behind a target object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to make camera track a sphere object from behind it.
The camera should capture it in middle while face same direction of the object's velocity direction.

And the distance between the camera and the object should be always same.

I could make the camera face same direction of the object's velocity direction by this code.

```
Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetRb.velocity);
lookRotation.z = 0;
lookRotation.x = 0;
camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(camera.transform.rotation, lookRotation, 0.4f);
```

But I can't find how to calcurate the position where the camera should be.

Could you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add e.g.

```c#
var targetPosition = targetRb.position - targetRb.velocity.normalized * DESIRED_OFFSET;
camera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(camera.transform.position, targetPosition, 0.4f);
```

which always moves camera towards a position `DESIRED_OFFSET` units behind the target.

---

or alternatively you could use the camera's current direction if you really want the sphere to always be fix in the center

```c#
var targetPosition = targetRb.position - camera.transform.forward * DESIRED_OFFSET;
camera.transform.position = targetPosition;
```

Or you could also `Lerp` this one again. I guess you have to try a few options and see what fits your desired outcome best.

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I want to do. I'm really appreciate it.